# Why my Caesar cipher code can not run?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int amount,i;
    char message[81],encry[81];
    printf("Enter message to be encrypted : ");
    gets(message);
    printf("Enter shift amount (1-25) : ");
    scanf("%d");
    for(i=0;message!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(message[i] >='A' && message[i] <='Z')
        encry[i]=((message[i]-'A')+amount)%26+'A';
    }
    printf("Encrypted message : ");
    int j;
   for(j=0;message[j]!='\0';j++)
    printf("%c",encry[j]);

 return 0;}
```

I try to write a caesar cipher code but it can not run. Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "cannot run". Providing more details on the error you are getting will be helpful for the people looking at you program. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4):

**1**.

```
 printf("Enter shift amount (1-25) : ");
 scanf("%d");
           ^ missing variable here (you need to pass an argument of type int *)
```

Where will you take input key then ?

You need to take input in `amount` variable like this -

```
 printf("Enter shift amount (1-25) : ");
 scanf("%d",&amount);
```

So , you don't store anything in `amount` and it is uninitialized .And you use it , therefore it causes undefined behaviour.

**2.** In this loop -

```
 for(i=0;message!='\0';i++)      // you compare here char * with char
```

condition should be -

```
 for(i=0;message[i]!='\0';i++)
```

**3.** Don't use `gets` to take input, it won't prevent overflow . Use [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) -

```
fgets(message,81,stdin);
```

Comment: @Corerid If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Error in `scanf("%d")`syntax it has to be like `scanf("<format specfier>",&variable);`

   So the fix is `scanf("%d", &amount)`
2. `int j;` is not a good practice to add the variable before for loop.

Comment: "_That works fine in c++ not in c_" -- It works fine in C99 and above as it provides support for mixed declarations and code.

Comment: Thank you. I will fix it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. Here:

   ```
   scanf("%d");
   ```

   The `%d` requires a second argument(of type `int*`) for storing the scanned number. You probably wanted:

   ```
   scanf("%d", &amount);
   ```
2. You are comparing a `char` and a `char*` here:

   ```
   for(i=0;message!='\0';i++)
   ```

   You probably wanted

   ```
   for(i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++)
   ```

---

Don't use `gets()` as it is deprecated. Use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin);
```

Note that `fgets` consumes the newline character and stores it in `message`(if there is space).